# emacs auto-complete key binding didn't work

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I downloaded an emacs configure file from here: https://github.com/redguardtoo/emacs.d 
I install it and learning to use emacs.
When used YASnippet, I found auto-complete's key binding didn't work.
When writing C code, type "inc" and then press TAB, emacs pop up a menu to choose a snippet. 
It works only when press uparrow and downarrow if I want to choose the a snippet, C-n and C-p didn't works.
I found that the emacs configure file has binding C-n and C-p. Here is init-auto-complete.el

```
(require 'auto-complete)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
(setq ac-auto-start nil)
(setq ac-dwim nil) ; To get pop-ups with docs even if a word is uniquely completed
(define-key ac-completing-map (kbd "C-n") 'ac-next)
(define-key ac-completing-map (kbd "C-p") 'ac-previous)

;;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Use Emacs' built-in TAB completion hooks to trigger AC (Emacs >= 23.2)
;;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)  ;; use 'complete when auto-complete is disabled
(add-to-list 'completion-styles 'initials t)

;; hook AC into completion-at-point
(defun set-auto-complete-as-completion-at-point-function ()
  (setq completion-at-point-functions '(auto-complete)))
(add-hook 'auto-complete-mode-hook 'set-auto-complete-as-completion-at-point-function)


(set-default 'ac-sources
             '(ac-source-dictionary
               ac-source-words-in-buffer
               ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers
               ac-source-words-in-all-buffer))

(dolist (mode '(magit-log-edit-mode log-edit-mode org-mode text-mode haml-mode
                sass-mode yaml-mode csv-mode espresso-mode haskell-mode
                html-mode nxml-mode sh-mode smarty-mode clojure-mode
                lisp-mode textile-mode markdown-mode tuareg-mode
                js3-mode css-mode less-css-mode))
  (add-to-list 'ac-modes mode))


;; Exclude very large buffers from dabbrev
(defun sanityinc/dabbrev-friend-buffer (other-buffer)
  (< (buffer-size other-buffer) (* 1 1024 1024)))

(setq dabbrev-friend-buffer-function 'sanityinc/dabbrev-friend-buffer)


(provide 'init-auto-complete)
```

I think this two line should works but it didn't. That draws me crazy.
    (define-key ac-completing-map (kbd "C-n") 'ac-next)
    (define-key ac-completing-map (kbd "C-p") 'ac-previous)

How can I bind C-n and C-p to choose the snippet in the pop up menu?

Answer (score 3):

I found in http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/auto-complete.el

```
;; Use C-n/C-p to select candidates
;; --------------------------------
;;
;; Add following code to your .emacs.
;; 
;;     (define-key ac-complete-mode-map "\C-n" 'ac-next)
;;     (define-key ac-complete-mode-map "\C-p" 'ac-previous)
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define-key ac-menu-map (kbd "C-n") 'ac-next)
(define-key ac-menu-map (kbd "C-p") 'ac-previous)
```

how about the above code

Comment: It doesn't work. But I found something more useful that C-n and C-p.For example when popup menu is "-include..." and "include..", I can press "-" for the first one and "i" for the second one. Problem solved. Thank you!